TYPO3: Override RTE CKEditor configuration preset for plugin flexform
In my TYPO3 sitepackage extension I have two different CKEditor configuration presets: a default one and a minimal one with less options.
In my page.tsconfig I define the default configuration and set the minimal configuration for certain fields, which works well for regular tt_content fields as well as for RTE text fields of other extensions. I cannot make it work though for text fields in a plugin flexform.
According to documentation it should work by using RTE.config.[tableName].[flexForm.field.name].preset even with an example for tt_content as tableName – but it doesn’t. Is there any mistake I overlook?
page.tsconfig
RTE {
    default.preset = MyDefaultCKConfig
    config {
        tx_another_extension_model_xyz {
            ## this works
            field_name.preset = MyMinimalCKConfig
            another_field_name.preset = MyMinimalCKConfig
        }
        ## the following does not work
        tt_content.settings.flexform.textAdd.preset = MyMinimalCKConfig
    }
}

Plugin Flexform definition (excerpt)
<settings.flexform.textAdd>
    <TCEforms>
        <exclude>1</exclude>
        <label>LLL:EXT:tx_another_extension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:flexform.pluginName.textAdd</label>
        <config>
            <type>text</type>
            <cols>40</cols>
            <rows>5</rows>
            <enableRichtext>true</enableRichtext>
        </config>
    </TCEforms>
</settings.flexform.textAdd>


Is the tablename of the extension records "tx_another_extension" or maybe "tx_another_extension_model_something"?

@UnpassableWizard: thank you for your note. You are right indeed. However, this section is the one that worked (I had replaced the original names and made the mistake forgetting the model). The one that does not work is
tt_content.settings.flexform.textAdd.preset = MyMinimalCKConfig
I added the model to the code and comments on what is working and what isn’t.

You might need to escape the dots in your flexform field name using a backslash, e.g. tt_content.settings\.flexform\.textAdd.preset

Oh, wow! @christian-fries: that works, thanks a lot. I find it a bit strange though, I would never have thought of this idea. I don’t think I ever escaped a dot in a tsconfig and this isn’t clear from the documentation.

TSconfig is a hierarchical structure in which each dot marks the start of a new level. If the field name contains dots, these must be escaped to avoid starting a new level. I created a MR to update the documentation.

The comment by Christian Fries revealed the solution. I post it here so that others can find it more easily.
The dots in the actual settings field settings.flexform.textAdd – and only these – need to be escaped:
RTE {
    default.preset = MyDefaultCKConfig
    config {
        tt_content.settings\.flexform\.textAdd.preset = MyMinimalCKConfig
    }
}

